# How can I dismiss several controllers ?

Tags: iphone, ios5

Using storyboard , I'm invoking a segue (set type to modal) in order to display the second controller , and the same way to display the third controller. A->B->C. I expect dismiss B and C together , and return to A. There was no navigation view controllers , no `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` .

In docs:

If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

I tried a variety of ways but failed. Am I missing something really simple ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Also try This

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```